# Javascript(jquery) created html disappears in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using a JSON data file to store data for a website.

Using JQUERY to retrieve the data and display it on a webpage.

```
$('#rescueList').append('<ul id="rescueListUL">');
if (val.rStatus === 'adoptable') {
$('#rescueListUL')
.append('<a href="#" class="rescueLink"  data-val = "' + key + '"><li class="rescueList"  ><img src="image/pug/'+ val.rYear+'/' + val.rImage1 + '"  height = "200em" alt="' + val.rName + '" /> '
+ val.rName
+ '</li></a>');
}
```

Firefox, Chrome, and IE 8 display a list of links that when clicked on display detail data.

When IE11 was used to view the page, the list will populate, however the list vanishes when the cursor is over the list.

The page displays the list with status of adoptable, a table of the status adopted, and another list of status memorial.

The adoptable list is set as the block view while the others are hidden.
When the element on the adoptable and memorial list is clicked, the list is hidden and a detail element is populated and displayed.

How can this be modified to avoid this issue?
[Problem Page](http://midmichiganpugclub.com/mmpcRescue.html)

Comment: An anchor TAG cannot be direct descendant of UL element, only LI can be. You are generating invalid HTML markup

Comment: You put `li` in `a` but it has the be the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, I am ashamed to say that I am aware that it should be that way, but it didn't occur to me that I had violated that principle.

Answer (score 0):

I check your code in page and i see some problems

- I did not see ul close tag (maybe i miss it)
- In html there is some bugs

  ```
  <button  class="btn btn-default"id="showAdopted">Show Adopted</button>
  <button  class="btn btndefault"id="showAdoptable" style="display: none;">Show Adoptable</button>
  <button  class="btn btn-default"id="showMemorial">Show Memorial</button>
  <button  class="btn btn-default"id="showListA" style="display: none;">Show List Adoptable</button>
  <button  class="btn btn-default"id="showListM" style="display: none;">Show List Memorial</button>
  ```

there is no space between class and id

Gennerally Chrome, Firefox better handle this type of bugs than IE and insert close tags if it recognize that it not exist. 
Unfortunately i don't have IE 11 to check what exactly cause the problem. Hope this help

Comment: Additional if you build page like this i would advise you to use `var ulelement = $("<ul />").attr('id','rescueListUL') $('#rescueList').append(ulelement )` rather than `$('#rescueList').append('<ul id="rescueListUL">');` It is a little slower but will avoid the mistakes of not closed tags

Comment: Fixed the no space issue and included the suggested variable method. Will have to wait to see if the IE11 will accept the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page you linked, the jQuery script is different from your example, still the problem addressed by others that you put a-tags as a direct child on a ul-tag is there. That's not good, but changing the following in your CSS seems to fix the problem you describe in IE:

```
.rescueList {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 2%; /* <-- REMOVE THIS! */
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Use tools like Firebug or the F12 developers tool in IE to debug these kinds of issues efficiently.

As a side note, there are some problems with your solution in general, like:

- You have a lot of invalid HTML code.
- You are using percentages for top and
  bottom margins.
- You have a lot of redundant Bootstrap classes to your
  code (e.g. "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12").
- You are using in-line styling to override or add to the Bootstrap CSS.
- You are scaling huge images using CSS.
- Your web server is not properly configured.

I'm not telling you this to be a pain. I realize that these things may be related to the page perhaps being a work-in-progress. Nevertheless, I hope the heads-up on some of these things will be of help to you in the progress of wrapping it all up. Also, a lot of these things are not desirable even for a work-in-progress, as they make such a fertile ground for hard-to-crush bugs.

Comment: Migrated an old table layout website to bootstrap. Learning as it was built how to configure. Is there a better way to scale the images? What configuration issue do you see?